# Why is the feature direction chosen in the direction associated with largest eigenvalue of $\Sigma_T$ in case of more than two classes?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, feature-selection

Why is the feature direction chosen in the direction associated with largest eigenvalue of  $\Sigma_T$ in case of more than two classes? Please see the following.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the context of this information? What algorithm is it describing?